# How does google chromium get current tab URL?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

The clipboard of google chromium seems like an independent module at `src/ui/base/clipboard`, no browser or web content instance has been called by clipboard. Does anyone know how to get current tab URL when copy/paste at google chromium? Thanks in advance.

Comment: copy/paste from render process or browser process?

Comment: @Asesh copy/paste from render process.